# C# - Alto consumo de memoria usando iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp, itext

Tengo el siguiente código, el objetivo es abrir un archivo `pdf`, calcular el `hash` del mismo y mantener el archivo en memoria (aproximadamente 20 segundos) para posteriormente firmarlo y guardarlo. Que ocurre, se carga un `pdf` de *90mb* y al abrirlo y mantenerlo en memoria el consumo se dispara hasta *1.2gb*:

```
entitySing.output = new MemoryStream();
entitySing.sap = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(new PdfReader(entitySing.inputBase64File),
entitySing.output, '\0', null, true).SignatureAppearance;
entitySing.sap.SignatureGraphic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(FileProcess.CompanyStampImageByte());
if (entitySing.digitalSign.Visible)
    entitySing.sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(float.Parse(entitySing.llx), 
                                       float.Parse(entitySing.lly), float.Parse(entitySing.urx),
                                       float.Parse(entitySing.ury)), 1, null);
```

Lo anterior solo es la parte del `pdfreader` y `pdfstamper` que según el seguimiento realizado son los objetos que se estan llevando la memoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma es, cargar el arreglo de bytes en el pdfreader de la siguiente forma:

```
                PdfReader myPdfReader = new PdfReader(
                new RandomAccessFileOrArray(byteArray))
```

y este pdf reader cargarlo en el siguiente pdfStamper:

```
                PdfStamper.CreateSignature(myPdfReader,
                myOutputFileStream, '\0', MyTempFile, true)
```

y antes del reader y el stamper crear el archivo temporal MyTempFile:

```
                MyTempFile = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()                                         + ".pdf";
```

Antes el proceso, con un archivo de **90mb** me consumia de **1.2** a **1.5** gb de memoria. Ahora recien abre el archvio queda en **200mb** y mientras se firma sube maximo hasta **330mb**. La mejora es notable.